# Javascript application is unable to return JSON data from API, blocked by CORS policy.

Tags: javascript, json, cors, cross-domain, ebay-api

When making a request to ebay's api for sold items via findCompletedItems I am getting the following error in chrome: Redirect location 'about:blank' has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.

In safari I get the following error: Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

When I enter the request url directly into the browser it returns the correct data in JSON format wrapped in callback which is what my research pointed me toward in order to get around this Access Control issue but despite my return being wrapped in a callback I still cannot get to the data to parse it because I get the previously mentioned errors at XMLHttpRequest.

Here is the code:

```
function getGearName(){
  var gearName=document.getElementById('gearInput').value;
  console.log(gearName);
  buildRequestUrl(gearName);

};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var shouldBeAsync = true;
var method = "GET";


function buildRequestUrl(equipmentName) {
  var baseURL = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-VERSION=1.7.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=AppName&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=processData&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=";
  var searchTerm = equipmentName.split(' ').join('+');
  var endURL = "&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value=3000&itemFilter(1).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(1).value=true&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2";
  var url = baseURL.concat(searchTerm, endURL);
  alert(url);
  console.log(url);


  var requestURL = url;
  xhr.open(method, requestURL, shouldBeAsync);
  //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.send();
  getResponse();

}

function getResponse() {
  var response = xhr.responseText;
  alert(response);
  console.log(response);
  processData();
}



function processData(root) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    alert(response.curentPrice);
    console.log(response.currentPrice);
  } else {
    alert("error getting data");
  }

};


</script>
```

The HTML file containing the JS is being run on a local apache server. Been searching around on here and elsewhere and feel like I have reached a roadblock in my understanding of how to get around this CORS issue. If anyone has any insight I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: If the data is wrapped in a callback then that's JSON-P, not JSON. You wouldn't normally do a JSON-P cross-domain request as an Ajax request, you'd probably do something like what is shown in [this tutorial](https://sacha.me/articles/jsonp/). (Or use a library that does it for you.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)